# The use of which verb is correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, verb-agreement

"3 generations of stupidity is enough."
OR
"3 generations of stupidity are enough."?

P.S. in the book Grammar in Use (advanced) the author suggests that when the complement is a singular noun phrase (though our complement here is an adverb (=enough)) a singular verb must be used. I believe the exact example was "3 hours is a long time (=the singular noun phrase) to take on the homework." However, I once heard a lawyer use "are" in a very formal and eloquent speech before the judge, which I think negates what the book says.

Comment: It's the stupidity that's enough, not the generations.  "Six tons of stupidity is enough."

Answer (score 1):

The principles relevant in this case are "1" and "22" int he following reference: [UWF WRITING LAB](https://uwf.edu/cassh/support-resources/the-uwf-writing-lab/access-materials-for-self-guided-study/grammar-and-punctuation/introsubverbagr/).

> 1  A verb must agree with its subject, not with any additive phrase in the sentence such as a prepositional or verbal phrase. Ignore such phrases.
>
> Example: Your copy (of these rules) is on the desk.
>
> Example: The video will not be available until the dispute (over video rights) is settled.

> 22   Nouns expressing time, distance, weight, and measurement are singular when they refer to a unit and plural when they refer to separate items.
>
> Example: Fifty yards is a short distance.
>
> Example: Ten years have passed since I finished college.

In your sentence there is evidently the choice of considering "3 generations" as either a unit or as separate items; it's a matter of context. The two examples I constructed below seem to fulfil respectively the two criteria.

- Since my great grand-father started studying the question until today we all failed to understand that, but 3 generations of stupidity **is** enough, we have got to do something about it.
- My great grand-father didn't understand and thought nothing of it, nor did my grand-father and my father who thought no better in connection with this question, but 3 generations of stupidity **are** more than enough, I can do something about it and will.

Comment: That was very thorough and helpful. Much appreciated.